# Converting a one-to-many xml design to a many-to-many

Tags: design, xml, data-modeling

I have an xml file format that looks something like this:

```
<topLevelTag>
  <category name="foo">
    <item attrib="value">ItemName</item>
    <item attrib="value2">AnotherItem</item>
  </category>
  <category name="bar">
    <item attrib="value">ItemName</item>
    <item attrib="value2">AnotherItem</item>
  </category>
</topLevelTag>
```

The code that parses this creates an instance of `ItemName` and is told that it's one category is, in the first case, `"foo"`, and then creates a second instance of `ItemName` which has associated category `"bar"`.

The problem is that I need to redesign the system so that each `Item` can have more than one `Category.` But I still need to be able to create multiple items as well. For example (using bullets instead of xml) I might need to create the following instances:

- `ItemName`

  - Primary Category - `"foo"`
  - Secondary Category - `"bar"`
- `ItemName`

  - Primary Category - `"bar"`
  - Secondary Category - `"foo"`
- `ItemName`

  - Primary Category - `"foo"`
  - Secondary Category - `"quux"`
- `AnotherItem`

  - Primary Category - `"baz"`
  - Secondary Category - `"foo"`
  - Tertiary Category - `"monkey"`
  - etc ... (no cap)
- `StillAnotherItem`

  - etc ...
- etc ... (no cap)

How can I design my XML format to encapsulate this many-to-many relationship?

---

> I am aware this question is on the borderline between StackOverflow and Programmers. I chose to put it here because it is a [*software architecture and design*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question. If not please let me know and I'll be happy to move it. [Precedent one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175609/how-to-structure-a-xml-based-order-form-using-asp-net) | [Precedent two](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151606/conditional-attribute-in-xml-most-concise-solution) | [Precedent three](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194058/structuring-the-xml-response)

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you use the same structure as in your bullets?

```
<topLevelTag>
    <item id="1">
        <value>ItemName</value>
        <category level="primary">foo</category>
        <category level="secondary">bar</category>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
        <value>ItemName</value>
        <category level="primary">foo</category>
        <category level="secondary">bar</category>
    </item>
</topLevelTag>
```

(the "id" distinguishes two instances of the same itemName).

For sure, you can't have a "many to many" structure explicitly - you must pivot (root?) either on item, or on category, since you need a hierarchical data set.

Or you change completely layout and pivot on the many-to-many relationship; this is easiest to convert to and from a RDBMS storage.

```
<topLevelTag>
    <item id="1">...</item>
    <category id="1">foo</category>
    <mapping>
        <map item="1" category="1" />
        <map item="1" category="2" />
        <map item="2" category="2" />
    </mapping>
</topLevelTag>
```

Comment: Can you explain and/or provide a link as to what you mean by "pivot"?

Comment: I am sorry, I am translating - English is not my native language, and I sometimes make up words. What I mean is that one type of node ("item") must be above and have "category" below, or vice versa; in the first case I would say that the structure is... *hinged*? on items, in the other, on categories. In the last example I'm using the term improperly, as all three entities are instances of something which is no longer a topLevelTag, but perhaps a collection, or a table.